# Which glue should I use to fix the interior covering of the roof of my cab?

Tags: interior

I have a London cab Tx1 model R reg.

I am looking for a specific glue to fix the interior covering of the metal roof. The foam/sponge on the back of this covering has crumbled, causing the covering to fall off the roof of the cab. Whichever methods I have used so far e.g. superglue, carpet sticking spray etc. to stick the covering back onto the roof have not worked because of the crumbled foam/sponge.

Please could anyone advise me on which glue to purchase for this issue and where from?

Thank you for your time.

Comment: I dont think the issue is so much the glue but the prep, you need to completely remove the crumbled foam and previous adhesive before using a new adhesive.

Answer (score 1):

Contact adhesive is the right glue to use, you spray it on both surfaces and wait for it to get tacky before sticking the material on. However if the material itself is degraded to the point it's crumbling then no adhesive in existence is going to work as the material won't hold together. You should get new material and clean the surfaces you are going to stick to to make sure they are free of loose material.